# AWS Update-GLUECrawler Powershell command looping

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-sdk, aws-glue

I am still in the process of learning powershell scripting and the integration with AWS.

The intended outcome of the script is to update a AWS Glue Crawler with new data stores (targets) with any S3 bucket directory path that is not already in the Crawler. The reason being that I need separate tables in AWS Athena. Currently the default behaviour is it creates a partitioned table if the schemas are the same. I have multiple directories in the S3 bucket and all files have the same schema. So my understanding is that I must define each path within the Crawler for them to be separate tables in Athena.

```
function Update-GlueCrawler($S3BucketSubdirectories)
{
  $Targets = New-Object Amazon.Glue.Model.CrawlerTargets

  foreach ($i in $S3BucketSubdirectories){       
    $Targets.S3Targets.Add(@{"Path" = "s3://" + $S3BucketName +"/" + $i +""}) | Out-Null
  }     

  Try
  {
      Update-GLUECrawler -Name $GlueCrawlerName -Target $Targets
      return $true
  }
  Catch [System.InvalidOperationException]
  {
      return $false
  }
}
```

This issue that I am having is that when the Update-GLUECrawler command is hit. The script hangs and eventually displays this error:

[image]

I have looked online and cannot seem to find a answer. Plus the documentation for this AWS command doesn't provide examples.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Are you able to change the name of your function from Update-GlueCrawler($S3BucketSubdirectories) to Update-GlueCrawlerTargets($S3BucketSubdirectories) as hinted at by Team Dev?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your function name is the same as the cmdlet function name you are trying to call?

Yeah :-) ...Team dev for life

Try the code to see how it loops.

```
Function Get-F1 #This is your function
{
Write-Output "Function1"
Get-f1 #This calls your function and gets stuck in a loop. Rename your function
    }



Function Get-F2 #This will be the AWS function
{
Write-Output "Hello"
    }


Get-F1
```

Comment: I have since noticed that and renamed the function but the same issue occurs. Thanks

Comment: If you run the below code in Powershell, it gets stuck in a loop

Function Get-F1 #This is your function
{
Write-Output "Function1"
Get-f1 #This calls your function and gets stuck in a loop. Rename your function
 }



Function Get-F2 #This will be the AWS function
{
Write-Output "Hello"
 }


Get-F1

Comment: Got your back here